# Перенаправить drill.html/****** на drill.html

Tags: html, .htaccess, редирект

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Как сделать так, чтобы после расширения .html убирался слэш и все что после него. Пока добился результатов просто убирать слэш, но если после него что-либо дописать (всё что угодно, кроме еще одного слэша), то слэш не убирается и ссылка уже выглядит к примеру так .html/fef2ff

Делаю редирект слэша вот так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правило сработает, если после `.html` есть слеш (а после слеша может ни чего не быть, а могут быть другие символы - маркер окончания строки не указан в правиле).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+\.html)/ $1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```